# Most efficient way of "pushing" data to Polymer elements

Tags: javascript, websocket, polymer

I have a situation in which I get data over a web socket, and performance is important. From the docs I understand that there are various ways of "pushing" the data I'm receiving to my Polymer elements, but I'm curious which one will be most efficient. So far I've created an element that can be included in a template, where the parent element will observe any changes in the `data` property and react accordingly. I've also been experimenting with using a Behavior to accomplish the same thing, though instead of needing to include a `"data-element"` in its template, it could just observe its own data property. I realize I could also use something like `iron-signals` to "push" the data via an event.

I'm not sure any of these methods are very efficient, since most of the time the changes to the "data" object will only apply to a small subset of all the observers. Another possible solution would be to "observe" a dynamic path, so like `data.pathx` instead of `data.*`, which would drastically reduce the number of times the observer callback gets fired, but I haven't come across anything that leads me to think that's possible, since each of my elements won't know if it should observe `pathx` or `pathz` until creation.

Like I said, performance is vital, and I feel there is way too much inefficiency if I have a small to medium sized `dom-repeat` of elements each observing a large `data` object of another element or individually holding a copy of that data on their own (like I assume a behavior would accomplish?).

I've looked at `iron-meta`, but I haven't been able to successfully data-bind to it, and from what I can tell from the docs, this data needs to be queried, whereas I need to be notified of changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer doesn't really "observe" changes in elements. It just sets a setter for each property, and when it's called the UI is updated. So a dom-repeat template will not observe any change inside an object bound to it.

What could impact performance is unnecessary DOM manipulation, so if just a small subset of the data changes, re assigning all the array to the property is not ideal, and you should use notifyPath with just the sub property path and value that changed. Polymer will only update the DOM nodes affected.

If you have a way of knowing what sub properties changed in your data then you could obtain the object paths that have changed and call notifyPath for each of those and only a small number of DOM nodes will be changed.

Additional note:
If the number of elements in your array change, (added/removed) you should use the Polymer base array manipulation methods to update the property of your Polymer element, so it will change the DOM efficiently.